# Check row count of before returning ref cursor in PL/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

In a loop I am calling a parameterized cursor. In any certain step, if the cursor returns row, this loop ends an I have to return the cursor as ref cursor. How can I check the rowcount without executing same query twice?

```
procedure pr_test
(
    v_data varray;
    ,ret_data sys_refcursor
)
as
    cursor c_q(x)
    select * from table
    where col1 = x;
    ...
begin
    ...
    for  in 1..v_data.count loop
        open ret_data for c_q(v_data(i));
                 ----- here some logic is required --------
        /*if rowcount of re_data > 0 then
            return ret_data;
        else
            close ret_data;
        end if;*/
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: So what's the deal? You open the cursor and return it. If there's no data, the caller (who's using the cursor) just has to handle the NO_MORE_DATA exception that will be raised - which they'll need to do anyways because eventually the cursor will run out of data. IMO reading an unknown-and-potentially-large number of rows into memory is not a viable solution, and at my place of business this would not get past code review. YMMV. Share and enjoy.

Comment: In the code you can see the return is inside for loop. Infact in simple way u can think the target is to return a cursor when there is a data else check with next driving for loop element. if we open the cursor, it can not be returned. So for the target cursor that contains record can not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to achieve that. Cursors act as producer-consummer design patter. It means than nobody can know how many rows will be retuned until the cursor is fully fetched.

In OCI you could use rewindable cursors - these cursors can be rewind back to beginning, but as far as I know these are not accessible from PL/SQL.

Comment: Ok .. :( Is it possible to use some collection? which will be defined with "%ROWTYPE" and that collection will be returned from the proc?

Comment: @user1027056 yes in case of collections this could work. I would also say that in might be faster (as long as you do not put more than cca 100000 rows into a collection)